# Loop through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm working on a component that displays information from an array on click of an image.

Without going into a lot of detail, for each of the 12 images I have displaying, they have certain ids that are relevant to that slot in the HTML. So `#person_0` is associated with `#bio_0`, `#close_0`, etc. And `#person_1` is associated with `#bio_1`, `#close_1`, etc.

What I am having trouble with right now is finding an efficient way to loop through jQuery similar to the below:

```
$( "#close_0" ).click(function() {
    $( "#bio_0" ).hide();
});

$( "#close_1" ).click(function() {
    $( "#bio_1" ).hide();
});

$( "#close_2" ).click(function() {
    $( "#bio_2" ).hide();
});
```

Rather than write this 12 times, is there a simple means to loop through this? What I'm clear on is how to pass in a variable into the div id (i.e. `#close_0` - where 0 would be the variable).

Any tips?

Comment: Just curious why you can't use a class for the `close` or the `bio`? Show us your HTML as well.

Comment: As @disinfor said, please show your HTML, the script could be very simple, or it could even be doable with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, if these elements have a class, then you would do `$( ".someclass" ).click(...`

If not, you can loop by ids like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<12; i++)
{
  $( "#close_"+i ).click(function() {
    $( "#bio_"+i ).hide();
    $( "[id^=person_]" ).removeClass("active");
  });
}
```

PS. I did not understand what you are trying to do with removeClass and if that's related to the elements you attach click events to

Comment: That's what I was trying to do initially but it doesn't seem to work. You can ignore the removeClass action - really I just want to loop those #close_ / #bio_ events

Comment: Actually, you're right - I'm just going to use a class since the only purpose is to close and it does not matter if every ID closes. Thanks for the help!